# Dask task/job queuing

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I've been using Dask for a good while but I still I don't know if there is a queue system for tasks by default. Let's say we have a local cluster and a client for it:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster

cluster = LocalCluster()
cli = Client(cluster)
```

I'd like to run, not in parallel but task after task (submit after submit, or future after future) the following:

```py
import time
a, b = cli.submit(time.sleep, 5), cli.submit(time.sleep, 1)
```

It's easy to see that these run at the same time since future `b` finishes before future `a`. My question is the following

- Is it possible to force that future `b` does not start before future `a` finishes?
- If tasks are heavy, I don't want that all of them are running in the same time, I'd like some queue system. Is dask-jobqueue way to go or what? I have no external queue systems available (slurm etc.)
- Or does the Dask-Scheduler somehow take care that it won't burden workers too much by scheduling too many simultaneous tasks?

Answer (score 0):

To have one task depend on another, you have some options:

- don't launch tasks until the previous ones have finished, e.g., by using the `.results` attribute to wait for them. In this case, Dask isn't doing much for you.
- set up your cluster to limit the number of worker threads to as many tasks as you think can comfortably run simultaneously, with appropriate arguments to `LocalCluster` (this is the preferred solution)
- have a task explicitly depend on a previous one, e.g.,

.

```
def sleepme(t, *args):
    time.sleep(t)
    print("done", t)

f1 = client.submit(sleepme, 5)
f2 = client.submit(sleepme, 1, f1)  # won't run until f1 is done
```